# AssertRaises in unittest not catching Exception properly in try except block

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file called test.py that contains this code

```
def divide(x,y):
    try:
        if (y==0):
            raise ValueError("Can't divide by zero yo!")
        return x/y
    except:
        print("Error my dude!")
```

And another file with my tests

```
class TestTestUnits(unittest.TestCase):

def test_divide(self):
   self.assertRaises(ValueError,testunits.divide,10,0)
```

If I run it, `assertRaises` doesn't catch the exception

```
    F..
======================================================================
FAIL: test_divide (__main__.TestTestUnits)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nacho/tdd/test.py", line 16, in test_divide
    self.assertRaises(ValueError,testunits.divide,10,0)
AssertionError: ValueError not raised by divide

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.003s
```

If I delete the try and except block, it works well. Is it because the except block catches it instead of `assertRaises`?

*Edit1: I need to have both `try/except` and `assertRaises` catch the exception!

Comment: You are catching the error within the function itself. The function will never raise an error externally. Remove `try/except` from the function, then unit test should work.

Comment: @pavel But what if I can't remove the try and except statements, it's there a workaround for this?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. Unit testing is meant to test the external effects of a function so that you can easily refactor the code. It doesn't matter what a function does internally as long as it produces the correct result. I also don't understand the idea behind raising an exception and immediately catching it. You don't need to raise anything but catch `ZeroDivisionError`...